# increment html anchor with arrow key javascript and/or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I making a little website where I must do like a powerpoint. I have multiple slides. I have hidden the scrollbar and diseable scroll. The only way to navigate between slide will be with arrow key and a link include in the slide.

Here the HTML code :

```
  <section id="s00" class="page slide">

    <a href="#s01" class="nextSlide"></a>
  </section>
  <section id="s01" class="page slide">

    <a href="#s02" class="nextSlide"></a>
  </section>
  <section id="s02" class="page slide">

    <a href="#s03" class="nextSlide"></a>
  </section>
  <section id="s03" class="page slide">

    <a href="#s04" class="nextSlide"></a>
  </section>
```

I've successfully make an jQuery script working for navigate between slide with arrow key, but I'm not very good in javaScript and I want to know if there a more efficient/cleaner/short way to do the same thing. The idea is to modify the page anchor with the arrow key. Here my jQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function upDown($dir){
        $url = document.URL; /*The current URL ex: http://***/presentation#s02 */
        $anchorNum = parseInt($url.slice(-2), 10); /*Get the anchor number from the current url ex: 02*/
        $urlNoAnchor =  $url.slice(0, -2); /*Get the base url without anchor number ex: http://***/presentation#s*/
        if ($dir == "up") { /*Increment or decrement the anchor number, up because the previous slide is up */
            if($anchorNum > 0){ /*We can't go under 0*/
                $newAnchor = $anchorNum - 1;
            }
            else{
                return;
            }
        } else{
            $newAnchor = $anchorNum + 1;
        };
        if ($newAnchor <= 9) {$newAnchor = "0"+$newAnchor}; /*if the anchor is equal or smaller than 10, need to add zero for keeping two units*/
        window.location.replace($urlNoAnchor + $newAnchor); /*Finally, redirect to the next or previous anchor*/
    };

    $(this).keydown(function(e) {
        switch(e.which) {
            case 37: // left
                upDown("up");
            break;

            case 38: // up
                upDown("up");
            break;

            case 39: // right
                upDown("down");
            break;

            case 40: // down
                upDown("down");
            break;

            default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
        }
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
    });
});
```

Thank you for your suggestion/help for helping me make better code :)

edit:
-I Know my code is limit to two digit anchor (00 to 99) because of the way I get the anchor number from the URL. For my project, it's not a problem, I will never have 100 slides, but if you know a way to make it (0 to ∞) I'm interested to learn.
- The parseint was also tricky for me to keep a leading 0, I don't know if I make it well.

Here the page where the presentation is : http://dubebenjamin.com/presentation/presentation#s00

Finally, this is the code I have make after suggestions :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Utilisation du clavier pour naviguer entre les slides
    $url = window.location;

    function upDown($dir){
        $hash =$url.hash.substring(1);
        $hashInt= parseInt($hash);
        if ($dir == "down") {
            $newAnchor = $hashInt + 1;
        } else if($hashInt > 0){
            $newAnchor = $hashInt - 1;
        };
        window.location.hash = $newAnchor;
    };

    $(this).keydown(function(e) {
        $key = (e.which);
        if ($key == 37 || $key ==38) { // left or top
            upDown("up");
        } else if($key == 39 || $key ==40){ // right or bottom
            upDown("down");
        };
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stick to jquery, as it can handle variations of browsers. I would do couple of improvements

1. Store the urlNoAnchor in variable instead of looking it up every time.
2. I would use plain if/else condition instead of switch case as it is pretty much just two conditions.
3. you can use window.location.hash to get and set the hash part of the url. You don't have to retrieve using slice() and append it seperately.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I just learn at this moment what is bash, this will certainly help me ! I will take in count also the two fisrt point you made

Comment: Finally I've principally take your advise for revising my code. The hash property was really the main change, and have simplify my script. I've also replace the switch for an if/elseif statement. For the urlNoAnchor, I didn't need it anymore. I will update my post with the new code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple way to make stuff happen on keyup events:

```
window.addEventListener("keyup",keyUp);

function keyUp(event_){
    switch(event_.keyCode){
        case 36:
            /* Left. */
            /* Your code for left key up here. */
        break;
            /* The other key cases... */
    }
}
```

If you want something more modular, you can store the key up or down values as Booleans to be referenced at any time, not just on `"keyup"` or `"keydown"` events.

You can store key values in an object:

```
var keys={left:false};

window.addEventListener("keydown",keyDown);

function keyDown(event_){
    switch(event_.keyCode){
        case 36:
            keys.left=true;
        break;
    }
}
```

But that is simple JavaScript. If your slide navigation is 4 directional, sort of like a tile based game map, maybe you should store your anchors as strings in an array. For example:

```
var slide_map=["anchor00","anchor01",
               "anchor10","anchor11"];
var slide_x=0;
var slide_y=0;

function getAnchorToAppendToURL(slide_x_,slide_y_){
    /* The value 2 is the number of columns in the slide map. */
    /* For this example slide map has 2 rows and 2 columns. */
    /* This formula is very simple and rids the world of 2d arrays. */
    return slide_map[slide_y_*2+slide_x_];
}

/* Inside the keyup event handler, the left key has been unpressed. */
case 36:
    /* Move slide_x position to the left, but don't let it go below 0. */
    slide_x=slide_x>0?slide_x-1:0;
break;
/* Then after your switch statement: */
window.location.replace($urlNoAnchor+getAnchorToAppendToURL(slide_x,slide_y));
```

Not sure if that's what you're looking for, but you could navigate through slides in four directions that way. If you know all of your anchor names and they're set up like: "anchorXY", you could literally avoid an array all together and just say:

```
window.location.replace($urlNoAnchor, String("anchor"+slide_x_+slide_y_));
```

Comment: If you're just using arrow keys to navigate through slides on a page, you only need a "keyup" listener. Keep track of the slide x and y position by updating it on keyup events, and use those values to determine which anchor to go to when your keyup handler function is called.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Basicly, I think your answer is too complex for what I looking for. I don't need to slide right/left, just up/down. Here the page : http://dubebenjamin.com/presentation/presentation#s00 where you can see the result.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're doing. I was thinking it was more like a tiled deal with images. Why not instead of getting the url every time your key event is fired, just store the current index in a variable. Like: `var anchor_index=0;` When you press up or down, modify that variable. Then, when you want to load the new slide: `window.location.replace($urlNoAnchor, "s"+anchor_index);` You don't have to worry about "s000" or "s00", Your names don't have to be a uniform length. You can use `indexOf("#")` to get the start index and length to get the end index of the url string.

Comment: I understant 60% of your sugession, and it's promising. I understand the fact I will decrement or increment index. Where I have more difficulty, it's the part where I get the current index(if I'm at slide 2 or 3 per example). If I take the information in the URL, I got stick with the parseInt and the way to manage the decimal.

Comment: What I'm saying is that since your page doesn't reload each time you press a key, you can store the slide index in a variable rather than getting it from the url every time you press a key. You can eliminate parseInt altogether unless you need it to get your current slide on the page's initial load.

Comment: Ok, I better understand now. I will try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

So, how I would do this is as follows:

```
/* Example url. */
/* example.com#s0 */

/* Say you have 10 slides. */
var max_slides=10;
/* Get the window url. */
var url=window.location.url;
/* Get the current anchor_index on page load. */
if (url.indexOf("#")!=-1){
    /* The page loaded with a hashtag, so you probably have your anchor specified in the url. */
    /* The +2 moves the start indext past "#s" in the url. */
    var anchor_index=parseInt(url.slice(url.indexOf("#")+2,url.length),10);
}else{
    /* Otherwise just set the start index to 0. */
    anchor_index=0;
}

window.addEventListener("keyup",keyUp);

function keyUp(event_){
    switch(event_.keyCode){
        case 36:
            /* If anchor_index is greater than 0, subtract 1, otherwise set it to zero. */
            anchor_index=anchor_index>0?anchor_index-1:0;
        break;
        case 38:
            /* If anchor is less than max slides, add 1, otherwise set to max_slides. */
            anchor_index=anchor_index<max_slides?anchor_index+1:max_slides;
        break;
    }

    /* Load up the new page. */
    window.location.href="example.com#s"+anchor_index;
    /* Or you can work the new anchor into the original url with the replace method. */
}
```

I hope this was more along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I will test tomorrow and come back to say the result !